# Make selectable value from sql

Tags: php, sql, list, dropdown

right now, my code populates a dropdown from a sql values, and I need to make a list without a dropdown, so that all values are shown right away and can be selected. 
COde is:

```
if ($show_display_name == "yes") {

$query = "select displayname from ".$db_prefix."employees where disabled <> '1'  and empfullname <> 'admin' and empfullname <> 'laco' order by displayname";
$emp_name_result = mysql_query($query);
echo "              <select name='left_displayname' tabindex=1>\n";
echo "              <option value =''>...</option>\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($emp_name_result)) {

    $abc = stripslashes("".$row['displayname']."");

    if ((isset($_COOKIE['remember_me'])) && (stripslashes($_COOKIE['remember_me']) == $abc)) {
        echo "              <option selected>$abc</option>\n";
    } else {
        echo "              <option>$abc</option>\n";
    }

}

echo "              </select></td></tr>\n";
mysql_free_result($emp_name_result);
echo "        <tr><td height=7></td></tr>\n";
```

Comment: remove the select\option stuff just echo the $abc; not sure aht you need help with

Comment: That does not work

Answer (score 0):

What about using radio inputs?

```html
<input type="radio" name="left_displayname" value="abc" /> Abc<br />
<input type="radio" name="left_displayname" value="def" /> Def<br />
<input type="radio" name="left_displayname" value="ghi" /> Ghi<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a multi select box. It will allow you to select multiple items. You can try the following:

```
<select name='left_displayname' tabindex=1 multiple size="4">
```

The size attribute controls the height of the selectbox. It can be adjusted as needed

Comment: This solutions seems fine, tnx. Only thing that is bothering me right now is font size inside the box....how to increase it?

Comment: You can add a CSS class to your selectbox. For example <select name='left_displayname' tabindex=1 multiple size="4" class="your-css-class">. You will then have to define your CSS class in a CSS file. For example .your-css-class{font-size: 10pt;} you can replace 10pt with the required font size.

Comment: Yes, I made CSS class and it works fine. Only thing that is bothering me right now is that this works OK on desktop browsers, I can select a name from list it highlighted and so on, but on mobile browser after selection it pops a popup in which I need to select one again. Any workaround for this issue? I tried at least seven browsers....